# ¿Cómo hacer que una clase herede métodos de varias clases en C# + Unity?

Tags: c#, unity, herencia, class

Estoy empezando con C# y Unity. Me gustaría hacer que la clase que controla mi Player herede métodos de otras clases igual que se hace en C++ pero no me deja poner de base mas de una clase. Basicamente quiero hacer esto:

Una Clase para controlar el Rigidbody:

```
public class Rigidbody2DHandler
{ 
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    public void SetVelocity(float speed_x, float speed_y)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed_x, speed_y);
    }
}
```

Otra clase para controlar el Transform:

```
public class TransformHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Scale(float scaleXYZ)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleXYZ, scaleXYZ, scaleXYZ);
    }
}
```

Y hacer que el controlador de mi player herede los metods de esas clases

```
public class PlayerMove : TransformHandler, Rigidbody2DHandler
{

}
```

Pero el compilador me da el siguiente error:

**Class 'PlayerMove' cannot have multiple base classes: 'TransformHandler' and 'Rigidbody2DHandler'.**

La pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna otra forma de poder hacer esto?

---

### Atualización

He encontrado esto en la web de Microsoft para solucionar el problema. Sin embargo me parece una autentica chapuza...

```
public class A {}
public class B : A {}
public class MyClass : B {}
```

[Fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1721)

¿Alguna solución mas elegante que esta?

---

**Atualización 2 (En respusta a la contestación de Carlos Muñoz)**

---

Si, hasta ahora lo estaba haciendo asi, usando la composición. Pero conociendo como funciona la herencia de clases lo veía poco práctico. Además se obtiene un código mas limpio y legible con la herencia de clases.

Ciertamente la extensión de clases ha resuelto el 99% de mi problema (por el momento). Pero hay casos en los que no tengo tan claro que sea la solución correcata. Por ejemplo el siguente caso donde tengo que usar funciones que pertenecen a clases diferentes y variables globales pertenecientes a la clase. Ahora mismo estoy testeando esto y tengo la sospecha de que esas variables estáticas podrian darme problemas.

```
namespace AnimatorExtensionMethods
{
        public static class AnimationsHandler                                
        {
            //---------------------------------------------------
            //variables que sospecho pueden dar problemas opr ser estáticas
            //---------------------------------------------------
            public static string stateName;   //nombre de la animacion actual
            public static float loop;         //Veces que se ha reproducido la animacion actual    
            public static AnimatorClipInfo[] clipInfo; //variable que no pertenece a la clase Animator

            //función que devuelve el tiempo normalizado de la animación
            public static float GetCurrentStateLoop(this Animator animator)
            {
                return animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime;
            }
            // Update is called once per frame
            public static void Update(this Animator animator)
            {
                stateName = GetCurrentClipName(animator);//es el nombre del clip no del estado
                loop = GetCurrentStateLoop(animator);
            }

            //función para saber si una animación se está reproduciendo
            public static bool IsPaying(this Animator animator, string state)
            {
                if (stateName == state && loop > 0.0f)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

            //Update is called once per frame
            public static void Update(this Animator animator)
            {
             stateName = GetCurrentClipName(animator);//es el nombre del clip no del estado
             loop = GetCurrentStateLoop(animator);
            }

            //retorna nombre de la animación actual
            public static string GetStateName(this Animator animator)
            {
                //con esta tengo la duda porque como "stateName" 
                //es una variable estática y hay varios animator
                //ejecutandose al mismo tiempo usando esta misma 
                //variable sospecho que en cualquier momento el
                //el código no va a funcionar
                return stateName;   
            }

            //retorna el tiempo normalizado de la animacion actual
            public static float GetLoop(this Animator animator)
            {
                //lo mismo en este caso y además estoy usando
                //el parametro "animator" que no se está usando 
                //dentro  de la función y el compilador me arroja
                //una advertencia de que esa variable no es necesaria
                return loop; 
            }

    
           /// retorna el nobre de la animacion que se está reproduciendo        
          public static string GetCurrentClipName(this Animator animator)
          {                     
             clipInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);           

             if (clipInfo.Length > 0)
                 return clipInfo[0].clip.name;
            else
                return "NULL";
         }

    }
}
```

Por el momento creo que si pudiera heredar esta clase y hacer una instancia única para cada elemento que use el Animator no ocurriría ninguno de esos posibles fallos.

Y la siguiente sería otra clase que también me gustaría que heredaran todos mis GameObjects.

```
public class CommonComponents : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// ---------------------------------------------
    /// Componentes
    /// ---------------------------------------------
    [HideInInspector]
    public Animator animator;
    [HideInInspector]
    public Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
    [HideInInspector]
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    [HideInInspector]
    public BoxCollider2D boxCollider;

    /// ---------------------------------------------
    /// función para inicializar los componenes y los manehadores
    /// ---------------------------------------------  
    public void Init()
    {
        ///conseguir componentes
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    }
}
```

No quise poner todo esto desde el príncipio para no liar al personal... pero bueno, ya hay una aquí un ejemplo mas realista de por donde van los tiros de lo que quiero hacer...

Todo tipo de ideas y/o alternativas a la herencia multiple de clases son bienvenidas.

Gracias!!

Comment: C# te permite una herencia de clase base, y heredar multiples Intefaces. Lo cual la solucion que te da Microsoft seria la correcta, o heredas una clase y una o varias interfaces.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar!! Si, puede ser correcta dependiendo de lo que se busque hacer... podria hacer esto: **public class TransformHandler: Rigidbody2DHandler** y luego esto **public class PlayerMove: Rigidbody2DHandler** Pero perdería toda la lógica del código ya que TransformHandler nunca va a usar métodos de Rigidbody2DHandle..  y además es lio terrible cuando quieres que la clase herede métodos de mas de dos clases.. En mi caso real quiero que herede métodos de 5 clases base diferentes y ninguna de ellas usa métodos de las démas... por eso digo que es una solucion valida pero chapuza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La herencia multiple no existe en C#

Y aún si existiera lo que tu necesitas no es herencia sino composición.
Es decir tu clase `PlayerMove` tiene mas sentido que sea algo así

```
public class PlayerMove
{
    private readonly TransformHandler _transformHandler;
    private readonly Rigidbody2DHandler _rigidbody2DHandler
    
    public PlayerMove(TransformHandler transformHandler, Rigidbody2DHandler rigidbody2DHandler)
    {
        _transformHandler = transformHandler;
        _rigidbody2DHandler = rigidbody2DHandler;
    }
}
```

Sin embargo guiándonos únicamente del código que has escrito la opción que tiene mas sentido es usando métodos de extensión.

Tienes que tener en cuenta que sin más código o explicación de tu modelo no es posible inferir un mejor diseño de clases que realmente resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Hola Carlos. Gracias por contestar. Te he respondido a tu comentarío ahí arriba (en mi pregunta). He puesto mas código y mas explicación. Creo que así se verá mas claro el problema que planteo. Ciertamente con lo poco que habia al príncipo tal vez no se veia demasiado claro. A veces tengo tendencia a simplificar demasiado para no confundir a la gente. Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución alternativa pero solo sirve para un uso generalizado porque usa métodos y variables estáticos. Lo dejo aquí por si alguíen tiene el mismo problema y le sirve de algo.

```
namespace Rigidbody2DExtensionMethods
{
    public static class Rigidbody2DHandler
    {
        public static void SetVelocity(this Rigidbody2D rb, float speed_x, float speed_y)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed_x, speed_y);
        }
    }
}
```

Se usaría de la siguinte forma:

```
using Rigidbody2DExtensionMethods;

public class PlayerMove
{
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rigidBody.SetVelocity(10f, 0);
    }
}
```

[Fuente:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Para mi preferible antes que la solución propuesta por Microsoft. Sin embargo esto no resuelve mi problema al 100%. Necesito herencia de clases multiple o algo similar que lo sustituya pues tengo métodos en clases que manejan variables que no pueden ser estaticas y deben heredarse. Si alguien responde a esa pregunta le estaría muy agradecido.
PS: Las interfaces y las clases parciales no sirven para este propósito.